# Why can't I see my script on ps program output?

Tags: bash, pid, ps

I have a simple script (x.sh):

```
echo $$
sleep 60
```

when I run this and "ps -ef | grep x.sh" I get nothing back.  Running "ps -ef | grep " I get:

```
jsm_adm+  7695  5700  0 12:25 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
jsm_adm+  7696  7695  0 12:25 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 60
jsm_adm+  7698  5841  0 12:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 7695
```

If I add "#!/bin/bash" as the first line x.sh then I get get:

```
jsm_adm+  7693  5700  0 12:25 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./x.sh
jsm_adm+  7694  7693  0 12:25 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 60
jsm_adm+  7701  5841  0 12:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 7693
```

Is there a way I can find that "x.sh" is running if the user hasn't put a hashbang as the first line of their script?  Also, what does "-bash" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not have a `bash` script in this `x.sh` file. The problem is exactly the hashtag `#!/bin/bash` you describe. If you do not put it into your file `bash` does not interpret your file as bash script. If you want to know more you could navigate to this [guide](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/basics) and have a look.

What occurs in your case is without the hashtag both command are interpreted as if you were typing them directly in the shell which you could observe in your first `ps` output as you see the program `sleep(60)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm sure this isn't how I've seen it work in older versions of BASH or KSH, but that was a while ago and memory isn't that good!

Comment: Yeah, it could be that in the past was handled differently and `bash` scripts were recognized using the extension. It could also be that different shells behave different. As far as this Q/A I am glad to help.